# Buddy build doesn't show exact line of code in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, crash-reports, buddy-build

I am using buddy build for crash reporting in my iOS app. I integrated the buddy build SDK as mentioned in the docs here:

https://docs.buddybuild.com/sdk/feature_settings.html.

I could see the stack trace of crash and it shows in dashboard . But it doesn't show the exact line of iOS code as mentioned in this link. https://www.buddybuild.com/features/mobile-usability-testing. 
Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Buddybuild stopped reporting the line of code for me as wel a couple of weeks ago. Haven't changed any settings or anything it just stopped working as intended. Same for a colleague of mine in another project.